# Is there a programming language with extensible enums?

Tags: enums, extends

Many object-oriented languages allow extensions of classes thus:

```
class Animal {}
class Cat extends Animal {}
class Dog extends Animal {}
```

However, when using enumerations there are cases where the opposite functionality is desirable. For example:

```
enum CatAction {
    meow, eat, sleep
}

enum DogAction {
    bark, fetch, eat, sleep
}

enum AnimalAction {
    eat, sleep
}
```

There is some redundancy here. An `AnimalAction` must be a `CatAction`, because if an arbitrary `Animal` can perform the action, then a `Cat` can perform it by definition. However, even languages with multiple inheritance do not allow defining `enum AnimalAction extends CatAction, DogAction {}`, and besides, that syntax does not avoid the redundancy.

This could be fixed with an `generalizes` or similar keyword.

```
enum AnimalAction {
    eat, sleep
}

enum CatAction generalizes AnimalAction {
    meow
}

enum DogAction generalizes AnimalAction {
    bark, fetch
}
```

This functionality also makes some patterns more convenient:

```
enum Direction2D {
    North, East, South, West
}

enum Direction3D generalizes Direction2D {
    Up, Down
}
```

Do any programming languages support this functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OCaml's polymorphic variants are close (although unlike enums, they are not numeric).

Here's the example:

```
type animal_action = [`Eat | `Sleep]

type cat_action = [animal_action | `Meow]

type dog_action = [animal_action | `Woof]
```

You can have multiple inclusion, but it is *inclusion*: this results in the union of the constructors in `cat_action` and `dog_action`.

```
type catdog_action = [cat_action | dog_action]
(* [`Eat | `Sleep | `Meow | `Woof] : that is, not what you wanted. *)
```

Polymorphic variants are actually a somewhat more complicated feature than this example suggests, but I don't think going into the details will help answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

C++ can in my opinion.

```
struct Animal{
  enum{
    eat,
    sleep
  };
};

struct Cat : Animal{
  enum{
    meow,
    glare,
    hiss
  };
};

struct Dog : Animal{
  enum{
    bark,
    fetch,
    peeOnCarpet
  };
};
```

The values of enums are in the same scope the enum is declared. However the first element of each enum starts at zero so unless you have specific animal/derivedAnimal functions you may want to ensure each is unique.

You can solve this by adding a marker in each base class, I'm not sure if I like it, however it works.

This code was written for an Arduino (C++).

```
struct Animal{
  enum Action{
    eat,
    sleep,
    die,
    end
  };
};

struct Dog : Animal{
  enum Action{
    bark = Animal::Action::end,
    fetch,
    peeOnCarpet
  };
};

void setup() {

  Dog d;
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println( "Values: " );
  Serial.println( d.eat, DEC );
  Serial.println( d.sleep, DEC );
  Serial.println( d.die, DEC );
  Serial.println( d.bark, DEC );
  Serial.println( d.fetch, DEC );
  Serial.println( d.peeOnCarpet, DEC );
}

void loop() { }
```